# Why the Output of Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "b") is -1. Please clarify

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String[] arr = { "c", "d", "b", "a", "e" };

        InnerClass in = new InnerClass();
        Arrays.sort(arr, in);

        for (String str : arr) {
            System.out.print(str + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "b"));
    }

    static class InnerClass implements Comparator<String> {

        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s2.compareTo(s1);

        }
    }
}
```

**Output e d c b a -1**

for information if we replace 
**Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "b") to Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "e")** the output is
**Output e d c b a -6**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array isn't sorted.

[`binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object)) only works on a sorted array:

> The array must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering of its elements (as by the sort(Object[]) method) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

Comment: if it's not sorted then why the output is -1. Could you please clarify

Comment: @dhS if it's not sorted, the result is *undefined*. Sometimes (i.e. for some unsorted arrays containing a `"b"`) it could be -1, sometimes it might just happen to find a result.

Comment: @dhS The explanation is in the API: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(byte%5B%5D,byte). The insertion point in your unsorted array was 0, according to the docs the value `(-(insertion point) - 1)` is returned, in other words 0-1 is returned, thus the -1.

Comment: @Paul if i search "e" the output is -6.. why so.. could you please explain further

Comment: @Paul no, it's undefined. It says that it will return the insertion point *provided it is sorted*. It doesn't say what it will return if the array isn't sorted. In fact, it literally says "If it is not sorted, the results are undefined".

Comment: @dhS don't try to understand it, beyond the fact that you are just using it wrongly.

Comment: @dhS I have a guess at why -6 was returned but knowing "why" will not help you do whatever you're trying to do.  Sort your array before calling `binarySearch` as required by the API.

Comment: @Paul it is an interview question. that's why i asked the reason ... but it is undefined i got the point Thanks.

Comment: @dhS but do you know *why* it's undefined?

Comment: @AndyTurner Because it is not sorted and binarysearch work on sorted array

Comment: @dhS but *why*? I would be pressing you for a much more detailed explanation in an interview.

Comment: @AndyTurner i searched but i am not getting that much information about -6. Could you share some information ?

Comment: @dhS Here's why you get -6.  If you look at the [binarySearch source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l1824) you'll see the search starts in the middle of the array. Since the value `e` is greater than the midpoint value the search continues to the end of the array (so `e` is then compared to `b` and `a`). The end of the array is reached so (as noted in the Javadoc), -(array length)-1 is returned which is -5-1 which is -6. Thank you for continuing to ask about -6, I feel better understanding the method now.

Comment: @Paul this is the best answer i got

Answer (score 4):

Your array is sorted in reverse (as indicated by your debug loop). Change your comparator to `return s1.compareTo(s2);`

Btw, Java's `String` class already is comparable, so I don't think you need to provide a custom comparator. The default will do.

`Arrays.binarySearch` requires the input array to be sorted according to the (ascending) natural order of its elements. If an element cannot be found, a negative number (e.g. `-1`) is returned as magic value. And elements can only be found if the precondition of "array has to be sorted" is met. Otherwise the result of the function is either a nonsense value or a negative result (negative being the lucky outcome, because otherwise you wouldn't know if your result was correct).

Comment: its is an interview question. Please clarify if it's not sorted so why it's giving the result -1

Comment: I think I explained a) why it is not sorted (or rather sorted incorrectly) b) how to fix your comparator c) when the result `-1` is returned. Most of it can be found in the [JavaDoc of Arrays.binarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(java.lang.Object[],%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: Is there anything unclear which is not answer by my explanation or the linked JavaDoc?

Comment: Your answer isn't correct: -1 isn't a magic value. As OP has commented, -6 can be returned too. If the array is sorted but the element is not found, the element would be correctly inserted at `~return value` (that's bitwise complement `~`, not unary negation).

Comment: Thanks, I've rephrased to "negative number" which should be true for all cases :)